# Collision: Picture Boxes but Top and Bottom only

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have two pictureboxes the other one must not touch its right and left. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: if the other picturebox touches right or left the original picturebox the other will go top or bottom

Comment: Yes it is, what exactly is your issue you are having? Can you post some sample code of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the picture boxes overlay with the `Location.X` and `Location.Y` properties.

To flip one picturebox to the top or bottom use the `SetBounds(x,y,width,height)` method.

Example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim xw = PictureBox1.Location.X + PictureBox1.Width
        Dim x2w = PictureBox2.Location.X + PictureBox2.Width

        If PictureBox2.Location.X <= xw AndAlso x2w < xw Then 'PictureBox2 touches right side of PictureBox1 => flip to bottom'
            movePictureBox(PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox1.Height + 5)
        ElseIf PictureBox2.Location.X <= xw AndAlso x2w >= xw Then 'PB2 touches left side of PB1 => flip to top'
            movePictureBox(PictureBox1, PictureBox2, -PictureBox2.Height - 5)
        End If
 End Sub

Private Sub movePictureBox(picFrom As PictureBox, picToMove As PictureBox, yOffset As Integer)
        'Set new location for picToMove according to picFrom.X and picFrom.Y + offset'
        picToMove.SetBounds(picFrom.Location.X, picFrom.Location.Y + yOffset, picToMove.Width, picToMove.Height)
End Sub
```